# FirebaseUI iOS remove cancel button

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm new in iOS development. I wanna build authorization with Firebase. I'm using FirebaseUI-iOS. I wanna hide Cancel button from the initial screen. Do you have any ideas how to do it?

I create Firebase authViewController programmatically:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuthUI
import FirebaseGoogleAuthUI

class AuthViewController: UIViewController {

fileprivate var _authHandle: FIRAuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle!
var user: FIRUser?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureAuth()
}

func configureAuth() {
    let provider: [FUIAuthProvider] = [FUIGoogleAuth()]
    FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()?.providers = provider
    FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()?.isSignInWithEmailHidden = true

    // listen for changes in the authorization state
    _authHandle = FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener { (auth: FIRAuth, user: FIRUser?) in
        // check if there is a current user
        if let activeUser = user {
            // check if the current app user is the current FIRUser
            if self.user != activeUser {
                self.user = activeUser
                let name = user!.email!.components(separatedBy: "@")[0]
                print(name)
            }
        } else {
            // user must sign in
            self.loginSession()
        }
    }
}

func loginSession() {
    let authViewController = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()!.authViewController()
    present(authViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

deinit {
    FIRAuth.auth()?.removeStateDidChangeListener(_authHandle)
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Besides from the answer given below, I thought you can do this in the Storyboard. Just search for the navigationItemLeft or something.

Comment: delete your section of code that specifies a left bar button item or just set it nil.

Comment: @TylerRutt I create view controller with this cancel button programmatically. I use FirebaseUI-iOS. I'm not sure have to remove button in this case. I updated my question with code. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried  `self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)`

Comment: @TylerRutt yes, I've tried. It doesn't help. I'm pretty sure that I have to call some method or change property of authViewController instance in loginSession. But so far I didn't find what to change.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Extend the VC and add it in the viewWillAppear

```
extension FUIAuthBaseViewController{
  open override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
  }
}
```

Comment: See Karen Hovhannisyan's answer for the canonical approach.

Answer (score 8):

You should set

```
FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()?.shouldHideCancelButton = true
```

Comment: One note on this answer: the line above should be called *before* instantiating an auth view controller with `FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()?.authViewController()`.

Answer (score 3):

For that you can set the `leftBarButtonItem` to `nil` in `viewDidLoad` or in `viewWillAppear`.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
```

Comment: The problem is that I create FirebaseUI authViewController programmatically. I don't know how to access its viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear methods. I updated my question with current code.

Comment: @VitaliiIvanov Have you try setting it in viewDidLoad of `AuthViewController`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried. It doesn't help. I've only found out how to hide the whole navigation bar. In loginSession function I can add authViewController.navigationBar.isHidden = true. But I only need to hide Cancel button.

Comment: @VitaliiIvanov Then try once `authViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil`

Comment: @VitaliiIvanov Don't getting it if `authViewController.navigationBar.isHidden = true` will works for you then `authViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil` should also work, try to put this line in completion block of present

Answer (score 0):

In Objective C, simply extend the FUIAuthPickerView Controller.

In ViewDidLoad of this extended picker view, add these two lines:

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;
[[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:nil];
```

Please note that in the file where you instantiate the Auth UI, you'll need this method:

```
- (FUIAuthPickerViewController *)authPickerViewControllerForAuthUI:(FUIAuth *)authUI {
return [[FUICustomAuthPickerViewController alloc] initWithAuthUI:authUI];
}
```